# Get elements value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor, as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="fpa2" value="7">
    <div class="pl2">
       <div class="pl3">Hero</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Using ***jQuery***, how do i get a variable with the value `7` from the value field on click?

I tried:

```
$('.fpa2').on("click", function(){
    var a1 = $(this).val();
});
```

but this is ***returning a blank*** value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.fpa2').on("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();  // this statement for prevent page reload
    var a1 = $(this).attr('value');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.fpa2').on("click",function(){
    var a1=$(this).attr("value");
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

**Check this code..**

```
$('.fpa2').click(function(){

    var value=$(this).attr('value');
     alert(value);
});
```